# Site navigation missing on ASPX page with read broken permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, permissions, administration, item-level-permissions

While in the middle of a migration from 2013 to SPO, I've broken the permissions of a subsite for the entire company to not have access to the entire site except a couple of ASPX site pages.  They can see the pages fine when directly linking to them, but the custom masterpage's site navigation is now blank where they had previous access to navigate between sites/links.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?  Is there a permissions level needed other than read access at the site level?

[image]

Comment: maybe I don't get your question. You said you have broken the permission of subsite, therefore your users do not have permission on the subsite level. Therefore they cannot see the navigation. So to fix it you only need to grant back the read (or above) permission to subsite level. Right?

Comment: @MarkL They can only see a few ASPX pages in the Site Pages library, given Read permissions (broken from denied site permissions).  They are not able to see any other elements of the site.  See the other comments below.

Comment: Could you post screenshot for the subsite level permission?  U can mask the usernames

Comment: @MarkL  Updated question with a screenshot. Pic1 - users do not see the inherited parent site collection menu in the subsite. Pic2 - Everyone removed from Read permission level at site level. Pic3/Pic4/Pic5 - Pages permissions broken to give directory.aspx Read access for Everyone.  When directory aspx page is directly linked to, users can view the page, in spite of not having permission to view anything else in the site, however they inherited have menu is missing.  Menu shows just fine on other sites.

Comment: Which group the "users" belong to? Everyone?
Also do you mean "users" have access to root site collection and all subsites? The only thing need to fix now is the navigation? If the navigation link to /sites/a/b/ please make sure "users" have permission on /b/ level. Not the individual pages.

Comment: @MarkL Those individual AD "users" where given more than Read access at the subsite level. "Everyone" was removed from all access at the subsite level.  Everyone has at least Read level access at the parent site collection level and other subsites.  The only thing needed is for the navigation to show on the aspx pages the "everyone" has Read access to (inspite of not having Read access at that site level).  "Everyone" has all the permissions they need in other locations.  In this migration, and I know this is unique, users needed to still access the directory page on the migrated site.

Comment: Do you know which way the navigation is built? Could you check site settings > navigation. If you see items under Structural Navigation, try to edit each item and see whether any "Audience" values

Comment: @MarkL The subsite nav being worked with shows: ---Display the same navigation items as the parent site (Parent is using Structural Navigation.)---

Comment: Then goto the parent site -> site settings -> navigation, to check the same things.

Comment: @MarkL I did.  Also, the other subsites work just fine.  The only thing altered, that is different, is this specific subsite.  All other sites behave as expected.

Comment: I cannot figure out what is the cause.  Since it is migration, maybe you just reset the navigation,  save and change back.

Comment: @MarkL That didn't work.  The global nav bar is still blank.  Please note that I can still see the nav inherited from the parent site collection because I'm SCA.  Here's my theory, when you remove the user's ability to read at the site level, even though you give them a pinhole through to a page, something is still not allowing them to see maybe the masterpage library/style library (which I can't grant people permission levels to).  Thoughts?

Comment: If so,  have you checked the code within master page?

Comment: @MarkL  <SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaDelegateControls" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:DelegateControl ID="DelegateControl2" runat="server" ControlId="GlobalNavigation" />
                <SharePoint:DelegateControl ID="DelegateControl3" ControlId="GlobalSiteLink3" Scope="Farm" runat="server" Visible="false" />
            </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>

Comment: I cannot tell what the master page do with part of the code. Maybe you can switch to OOTB master page to test the navigation first. If the link show up properly you can drill on the master page code. So far we can see your site have heavy customization. I suggest to check the past documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Mark.
Navigation links in the site are security-trimmed. If users don't have permissions, they won't see them.

So, in your SharePoint, users can not see the links in the site navigation because they do not have permissions for the pages linked by the links.

Only when users have read or above permissions for the pages linked by links, users can see the links in the navigation. You should grant users with enough permissions, then have a test, compare the result.

Comment: For clarity, they still have access to the root site collection and other subsites, and can see the site navigation in all the other sites.  What I'm trying to figure out is why the site navigation doesn't even show on the individual ASPX pages I've given them Read permission level to, but denied access to the rest of the subsite.